# How to format an algorithm using lstlisting

Tags: lstdefinestyle

I'm writing an algorithm using lstlisting :

```
 \lstset{language=C++} 
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption=Algorithme de la méthode "HOG+SVM"]
    HOGDescriptor hog;\\
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());\\
    while(1)
    {
        Mat image=imread("image.jpg");
        vecor<Rect> detected_persons;
        hog.detectMultiScale(image,detected_persons, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);
        for(int i=0;i<detected_persons.size();i++)
            {
                rectangle(image, detected_persons[i], cv::Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);
            }
        imshow("image",image);
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
```

But I got such output this algorithm:
[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS79K.png) How to fix that?

Comment: I think you should clarify what the expected output is and what precisely does not satisfy you in the output you are getting now.  The picture you posted is not very helpful.

Comment: `listings` is meant for typesetting code listings, not for algorithms itself, that's why there are packages like `algorithm` and `algorithm2e` etc. made for

Answer (score 1):

The `lstlisting` environment does not always look nice for long lines, as you have noticed. There are alternatives (e.g., `minted`), but you can adjust the `lstlisting` output to look better.

For example, the basic size can be set to small, lines can be wrapped (and indicated as such), indentation made smaller. The following MWE has been patched together from [listings: Set tabsize while using spaces for indentation in the loaded file does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129238/listings-set-tabsize-while-using-spaces-for-indentation-in-the-loaded-file-does) and
[lstlisting line wrapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/lstlisting-line-wrapping) and manually removing the top-level indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small,       % font size
    breaklines=true,         % line wrap
    postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},        % arrow on wrapped lines
    literate={\ \ }{{\ }}1   % adjust tab size
}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption=Algorithme de la m\'{e}thode "HOG+SVM"]
HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
while(1)
{
    Mat image=imread("image.jpg");
    vecor<Rect> detected_persons;
    hog.detectMultiScale(image,detected_persons, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);
    for(int i=0;i<detected_persons.size();i++)
        {
            rectangle(image, detected_persons[i], cv::Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);
        }
    imshow("image",image);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]