# Modify the lstlisting frame and properties

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, minted, sourcecode, sql

This is my options for the lstlisting ambient:

```
\lstset{language=SQL,frame=ltrb,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{OliveGreen},
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{CadetBlue}\bfseries, 
    commentstyle=\color{Brown},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
}
```

And this is the lstlisting ambient:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Creazione tabella 123r}]
            create table SP (
                SNum varchar(3),
                PNum varchar(3),
                QTY decimal(5) not null,
                constraint SP_PK primary key(SNum, PNum),
                constraint SP_FK_S foreign key(SNum) references S(SNum) on delete cascade,
                constraint SP_FK_P foreign key(PNum) references P(PNum) on delete cascade
            );
        \end{lstlisting}
```

But the frame of lstlisting is too small to hold in some cases the text in a single line as in the picture number 1. The problem is in the picture number 2.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

How can I solve this problem?

How can I align numbers with the text above?

Comment: Can you add complete MWE which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of your problem lies in the fact that you use too many spaces to indent your code in the `lstlisting` environment. Hence, you could use the `literate`  option to overcome the problem, as suggested here: [listings: Set tab size while using spaces for indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129238/listings-set-tabsize-while-using-spaces-for-indentation-in-the-loaded-file-does).

Here is a MWE that solves your problem by adjusting the number of spaces by using the package `listings`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{rgb}{0.94,0.95,0.96}
\usepackage{listings,eulervm,palatino}
\lstset{language=SQL,%frame=ltrb,
backgroundcolor=\color{background},
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{OliveGreen},
identifierstyle=\ttfamily\color{CadetBlue}\bfseries, 
commentstyle=\color{Brown},
stringstyle=\ttfamily,
tabsize=1,
% literate={\ \ }{{\ }}1, reduce the tab width from double to single spacing
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=2em,
% frame=single,
% framexleftmargin=1.5em % Uncomment these two lines if you prefer to have the frame
}

\begin{document}

\section*{DDL di creazione del database}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Creazione tabella 123r}, basicstyle=\small]
create table SP (
  SNum varchar(3),
  PNum varchar(3),
  QTY decimal(5) not null,
  constraint SP_PK primary key(SNum, PNum),
  constraint SP_FK_S foreign key(SNum) references S(SNum) on delete cascade,
  constraint SP_FK_P foreign key(PNum) references P(PNum) on delete cascade
);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:[image]

Another way could be using the package `minted`, which I find more straightforward than `listings`.

Here is a MWE using `minted`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{rgb}{0.94,0.95,0.96}
\usepackage{minted,eulervm,palatino}
\usemintedstyle[sql]{tango} % tango is the color style
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{List of source codes}

% : > pygmentize -L styles # shows all the possible color styles for the package minted
% : > pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex # compile with the -shell-escape option active


\begin{document}

\listoflistings

\section*{DDL di creazione del database}

\begin{listing}[ht]
\begin{minted}[gobble=1,
    bgcolor=background,
    fontsize=\small,
    linenos=true,
    xleftmargin=1.5em]{sql}
create table SP (
  SNum varchar(3),
  PNum varchar(3),
  QTY decimal(5) not null,
  constraint SP_PK primary key(SNum, PNum),
  constraint SP_FK_S foreign key(SNum) references S(SNum) on delete cascade,
  constraint SP_FK_P foreign key(PNum) references P(PNum) on delete cascade
);
\end{minted}
\caption{Creation of table 123r}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]